# Laravel eager load model relation using model instance?

Tags: php, laravel

Is there any other way to eager load the modal relation and avoid having `['invoicePayments']` array selector?

fx:

```
$payment->load(['invoice.source', 'invoice.user'])
            ->getRelations()['invoicePayments'];
```

The main reason is like this for now is because I am using model binding injection, so my method is just `function getInvoicePayments(Payment $payment)` but I feel this array selection is wrong, but I can't think in any other solution for it? any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

All of the following should be equivalent:

```
$one = $payment->load(['invoice.source', 'invoice.user'])->getRelations()['invoicePayments'];

$two = $payment->load(['invoice.source', 'invoice.user'])->getRelation('invoicePayments');

$thr = $payment->load(['invoice.source', 'invoice.user'])->invoicePayments;

dd($one, $two, $thr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also manually try to access every relationship's property, this will force Laravel to load the relationship in the model's instance:

```php
$payment->invoice->source;
$payment->invoice->user;
$payment->invoicePayments;
```

I actually don't like doing this, but it's another working way.